# Mapping items in list view to number of clicks

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView populated with a custom Array adapter. I want to get the total number of clicks on each item in the ListView .How can i map the listview item id and number of clicks on that item for multiple items?

Comment: you can store in arraylist with item position

Comment: setup `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` and update your data model inside `onItemClick` method, then call `Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.. exact.. hardcoded the whole code for you :p

```
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map_positions_and_count = new HashMap<>();

     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            for (int i = 0; i<listView.getAdapter().getCount()-1; i++)
            {

                if (i == position)
                {
                    if (map_positions_and_count .get(position) !=null)
                    {
                        map_positions_and_count .put(position,map_positions_and_count .get(position)+1);


                    }
                    else {
                        map_positions_and_count .put(position,1);


                    }



                }

            }
           // map.put(position,)


        }
    });
```

**You can use this in your mainActivity** ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your activity,

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();//make this as global

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(arrayList.get(position)!=null) {
                int a = arrayList.get(position);
                arrayList.set(position, a+1);
            }
            else
                arrayList.set(position,1);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ->

```
        final HashMap<Integer, Integer> listItemCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        //Set an onItemClickListener
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (listItemCount.containsKey(position)){
                    listItemCount.put(position, listItemCount.get(position)+1);
                }else {
                    listItemCount.put(position, 1);
                }

            }
        });
```